# Do Objective-C unit test resources add to overall file size

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, unit-testing, ocunit

I'm quite new to unit testing and I was wondering whether resources specific to the unit test add the the overall size of the app once it is built for the app store?

For example, I'm using set images for testing image manipulation. Will these add to the size of the built app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They will not if you do not add them to the to the applications main target but the test target.

I assume you are using two targets.

Explanation:
When an application is build, all sources are compiled to objects and linked to each other to form an executable. Parameters are passed to make the application work on the correct platform.
Resources are not part of that. They are added to a folder in the application.

(A .app file is actually a directory, you can see this by right clicking it and select 'Show Package Content')

Files which are not added to your applications target will not be placed in this folder.
So your safe.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I have seen on your site that you develop iOS applications, are you more familiar with Unit Testing on this platform? If you need more help, maybe you can contact me personally and I can help you on your way.

Answer (score 0):

> I was wondering whether resources specific to the unit test add the
>   the overall size of the app

They won't if you don't include them in the app target. You'll generally have a separate target for your unit tests, and any resources needed for the tests but not for the app itself, such as test data, should be part of the test target and not part of the app target. You can use the Target Membership pane in Xcode's file inspector (in the Utilities) to set which targets a given file belongs to.